# Page Not Founds Surfacing in [recent log entries] for all page--customnames.tpl.php

Tags: theming

My custom pages work great and cache fine; however, they trigger "Page not found" in recent log entries.  This does not occur with page--front.tpl.php or any other internal drupal paths.  I am mainly concerned for potintial performance risks which are mitagated through caching but still remain with dynamic pages.

I havent modified template.php or made any other changes besides creating the custom page (404's exist even if I clear the custom page entirly which seems like a configuration issue)

Any pointers would be much appreciated. I am using Drupal 7.14 and am comfortable makeing changes to absolutly everything including httpaccess if required.

Thanks,

-- b

Comment: How did you create your custom pages? `hook_menu()`? (page--front.tpl.php != 'internal drupal path')

Comment: I just created a file called page--custom.tpl.php and it is accessable by the path /custom and works fine but throughs not founds in log.